# Mapping by $f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$. Which of the following is/are true?

(A) $f$ maps $\{|z|<1\}$ onto $\{Re(z)<0, Im(z)>0\}$

(B) $f$ maps $\{|z|<1, Im(z)>0\}$ onto $\{Re(z)<0, Im(z)>0\}$

(C) $f$ maps $\{|z|<1, Im(z)<0\}$ onto $\{Re(z)<0, Im(z)<0\}$

(D) $f$ maps $\{|z|>0\}$ onto $\{Im(z)>0\}$

Based on some of the ideas I picked up from Mobius transforms and a whole lot of imagination I am convinced that only A and B are true.

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure there are no typos in your options? On the face of it, none of the available options seem correct.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized as it comprises multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $z=x+iy$ in right hand side and put $f(z)=u+iv$ in left hand side.Then simplyfy the right hand side and divide in real and imaginary part and compare with left hand side's real and imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bilinear (or Moebius) transformation:
$$
w = f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}
$$
whose inverse is given by:
$$
z = f^{-1}(w) = \frac{-dw+b}{cw-a}
$$
I've just studied the same transformation. Here is my suggestion.
With your data ($a=b=-c=d=1$), the condition $|z|<1$ is equivalent to:
$$
(w-1)^2 < (1+w)^2
$$
Substituting $w=u+iv$ gives finally the inegality:
$$
u>0
$$
Hence, $f$ maps $|z|<1$ (disk) onto Re(w)>0 (half-plane) which is not what you have proposed but may be are you considering the inverse transformation (the text is not really clear).